# TFS build agent updates

Tags: tfs, msbuild

My question may sound trivial, but I was not able to come to any conclusions after few days of research.
How often should one update build tools on production build agent.

Some details to understand why I have this dilemma.
On one side I would like to keep production build environment as stable as possible.
Currently using TFS server 2017, build agent uses msbuild that came as part of visual studio installation (VS2017 - 15.0.26228.0). We build C++ unmanaged apps.
Recently was chasing an issue where our app would get stuck for a long time for no reason (busy for 7-8 minutes, then continues). In the attempt to debug the issue, I created new executables from the same sources, but used different system to build it (it had VS2017 - 15.5.27130.2036). It was build from visual studio. I have noticed the size of exe was different and of course it did not have the issue with the freeze. Checking release notes did not help, I did not see anything that could explain the difference in produced binary.
I have to say, our code is bit complex, using number of third part libs, creating lot of complex structures in memory.
The area of the code that leads to a freeze has to do with reinitializing a lot of objects, recreating lot of vectors of complex structures...

Anyway, question is on how industry deals with updates to build tools in production environment. Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many methods for maintaining build environments so think you'll find it extremely difficult to get a industry standard approach.
I've settled on using virtual machine images and containers for providing, stable, repeatable environments.

System Center and a container registry are used to store the artifacts and I pave over the 10s of build servers each night to restore the VM images thus ensuring the same tool chains are in place day in and day out.

For upgrades, a new image is created with the new tooling and then tested in isolation before making it the default image. If the tool chain supports side by side installation like MSBuild, Typescript etc then there is very low risk of breaking something as the isolation of these tools is very good. I also find if the project files target specific tool chains rather than floating to the latest version automatically then your life will will be much more enjoyable.

Some tools are less than stellar in this area and tend to pollute the environment or restrict you to a single version of the tool. For this I fix them containers if possible. If this isn't possible then those tools get a new image, and a new set of CI boxes dedicated to that tool.

In general I subscribe to a pull model for updates, where the software is updated manually. This is critical when serving many developers across the globe and the CI environment simply cannot be flaky due to self updates.

Answer (score 0):

Every agent has a set of capabilities that indicate what it can do. Capabilities are name-value pairs that are either automatically discovered by the agent software, in which case they are called **system capabilities**, or those that you define, in which case they are called **user capabilities**.

You can view the system capabilities of an agent, and manage its user capabilities by navigating to the **Agent pools** hub and selecting the **Capabilities** tab for the desired agent: `http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool`

> These capabilities won't update by the build agent, if you want to
>   update them, you have to update them manually on your build agent
>   machine. After you install new software on a agent, you must restart
>   the agent for the new capability to show up.